# How to fix lodash vulnerabilities, is there an alternative to lodash?

Tags: reactjs, lodash, storybook

I'm working on a react project using a lot of lodash functions. The last update of lodash was 2021. Now yarn audit shows a number of vulnerabilities. Also packages like storybook, that use lodash internally throw errors.

```
high          │ Command Injection in lodash 
Regular Expression Denial of Service in tmpl 
....
```

Since there is no newer version of lodash, how can I go on with this project?

Comment: Look at where it's being used. If it's being used only by other trustworthy libraries (whose code is probably good and not so easily replaceable), it's almost certainly not worth worrying about. If it's being used in your main app too and you're worried, it's still pretty unlikely to be an issue, but you could probably easily refactor to vanilla JS.

Comment: @CertainPerformance lodash is also used by other packages, storybook e.g.

Comment: If you are refering to https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-29mw-wpgm-hmr9 then there is a patch in 4.17.21 so `yarn audit --fix` should fix this for you